# Hibernate criteria select all rows where value is first 5 chars of column value

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have entitity with field: `str` and table

```
str
12345675678
56334567676
46746764764
67345243524
```

I need write criteria query and select all rows where `str` contains my value. My value always first 5 chars of str.

if value= "56334" I need return `56334567676`

if value= "12345" I need return `12345675678`

I tried `Restrictions.like` but it not fund my row.

```
value= "56334";
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("str", value));
return criteria.list();
```

If it is native select it look like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntity t WHERE t.str LIKE '%12345%' // this select return success result. but my criteria return 0
```

Comment: Did you try changing ```value= "56334"``` to ```value= "%56334%"```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this something like this:

`criteria.add(Restrictions.like("str", value, MatchMode.START));`

[MatchMode documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html)

Comment: I found a solution sooner than you answer but it right!